# Question to the color scientists

Tags: eyes, light, senses

I have a question.
if you look at these two spectral diagrams (SPDs) from two different televisions that is calibrated to the same white point (D65) 6500K with a spectrometer.
The problem is that white still looks different to the eye here.
why does white look different is my question.

Television1
(pictures from avsforum)

[image]

Television2

[image]

A logical explanation would be great as i trying to figure out whats causing it.
is it the spectral power differences that causing it or is it the different distribution of the GREEN and RED with its more narrow peaks on television1 that causes it?
what i can see and what i understand is that Television1s spectral power will produce a more natural light as its more close to the warm light from an incandescent bulb.
Television2 reminds more of an typical LED lamp that we all know have a more harsh and poor light.

Comment: First: What is TV in this context? Then: LED lights are not necessarily cold, they can be produced in almost all color temps you want to have.

Comment: Tv=Television and ok cold is maybe the wrong term. poor and harsh is the right description.

Comment: The difference between both images can by explained with the spektrum. The upper one lacks most of the colors between green and red (more or less) while the lower one is more complete here. Both also differ in green.

Comment: Thanks for the input but i think its more about the different energy of Green and Red on the first television thats makes the difference. higher energy for Green and Red compared to Blue should make whites "look" more warm..while television 2 only has high energy for Blue it will give whites a more cold tone.  i have already captured the differences on whites with an DSLR camera but the differences on photo is not the same as i see them.. the camera sensor picks up the correct white for television 1 but not for television 2 for some reason.

Comment: i have already captured the differences on whites with an DSLR camera but the differences on photo is not the same as i see them.. the camera sensor picks up the correct white for television 1 but not for television 2 for some reason.. here is the differences for white with similar televisions models but not the exact ones from these photos..television 1 to the left..whites "looks" correct on the photo but white on television 2 looks too much Blue/Green. http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb192876/500M%20B7_2.jpg

Comment: it has nothing to do with computer graphics. where do you think its related to graphics from a computer?.. its more about how our eyes see light and colors different compared to spectrometers and cameras.

Comment: This is probably caused by the imperfection and/or mismatch between what your eye thinks white and the calibration device's white...color perception from spectrum can be nonlinear and have individual variations.

Comment: A simple observation: whilte points are a single dimension: temperature.  Color itself is a 3 valued thing (for human eyes).  Thus it will always be possible to have two colors with the same temperature.  Color temp is more useful if your source is blackbody.

Answer (score 2):

After more reading and information its quite simple.
our eyes picks up the energy from the primary colors.
if a television has higher BLUE energy than RED and GREEN that picture will have a blueish cold look to it even if its calibrated to D65

the SPD from television nr1 has higher energy for GREEN and RED and so whites on this television will look more warm and less blue.

how distinct and separate the cones are can also matter here.
television nr1 has no clear separation between GREEN and RED while television nr1 has.